# Why I get several errors when I try to upload my application for app store?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I try to distribute my app, I get Upload failed:

- Failed to authenticate (19)
- Session shutdown failed, Unable to send channel data (16)
- An authentication error occurred while uploading the package to Apple's remote server.
- Address not available (14)
- The transport has been detected as having stalled and has been aborted. Please try again.

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL8vV.jpg)

My app works great on my phone. I'm using core data and my deployment target is: 10.0

Please, does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your Apple ID correct in Xcode preferences?  Have you set up multi factor authentication for your Apple ID?

Comment: Yes, my Apple ID is correct and multi factor authentication is activated. Last week I have published 2 apps without problem

Comment: Is this your first time uploading an app binary to App Store that contains Core Data?  I have encountered a few errors in connecting the iTunes servers over the past several years.  One occasion involved Core Data.  I was forced to abandon the project altogether.

Comment: It looks like some sort of network error; Have you tried again?  Sometimes the application loader will work when Xcode doesn't

Comment: @El Tomato, Yes, this is my first project with core data, the first version of my app was rejected by apple, so I added new features to the app as core data, but when I try to distribute it, I get this message

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I restarted my mac several times, clean and build folder, change the version of build but I still get the same errors

Comment: I suppose your system clock is correct.  That can cause a problem.  I'm saying it because one of the error message refers to 1453670455, which corresponds to January 25th, 2016.

Comment: Yes, system clock is correct. I will create a new project with a different Bundle Identifier and if it does not work, I will try to remove core data and try again